# How to solve Invalid value javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:for confluent-platform in docker?

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-platform

Below is my Docker-compose file for adding Confluent-platform broker security

i tried so much ways,but it is not working.

i created the keys from my local and mounting to docker,thats works fine but  i didnt understand the exception.

```
    ---
   ---
version: "2.3"
services:
  zookeeper1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.1
    restart: always
    hostname: zookeeper1
    container_name: zookeeper1
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:5.5.1
    hostname: kafka1
    container_name: kafka1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper1
    volumes:
      - //d/tmp/keys/:/etc/kafka/secrets
   
    ports:
      - 8091:8091
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper1:2181
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 0
      KAFKA_BROKER_RACK: "r1"
      KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: SSL:SSL
      KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: SSL
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: SSL://kafka1:8091
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: SSL://kafka1:8091
      KAFKA_SSL_PROTOCOL: "TLSV1.2"


      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME: kafka.broker.keystore.jks
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS: password.txt
      KAFKA_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS: password.txt
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME: kafka.broker.truststore.jks
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS: password.txt
      KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH: "none"

      KAFKA_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: ""
```

But in the log i am seein glike this **truststore is not detected**

```
ssl.key.password = [hidden]

ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509

ssl.keystore.location = /etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.broker.keystore.jks

ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]

ssl.keystore.type = JKS

ssl.principal.mapping.rules = DEFAULT

ssl.protocol = TLSV1.2

ssl.provider = null

ssl.secure.random.implementation = null

ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
```

> ssl.truststore.location = null

> ```
> ssl.truststore.password = null
> ```

But i am facing the below error:

```
[2021-03-10 07:45:20,758] INFO Awaiting socket connections on 0.0.0.0:8091. (kafka.network.Acceptor)

[2021-03-10 07:45:21,049] ERROR [KafkaServer id=0] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)

org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: **Invalid value javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem for configuration A client SSLEngine created with the provided settings can't connect to a server SSLEngine created with those settings.**

at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslChannelBuilder.configure(SslChannelBuilder.java:77)

at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:157)

at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.serverChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:97)

at kafka.network.Processor.<init>(SocketServer.scala:769)

at kafka.network.SocketServer.newProcessor(SocketServer.scala:396)

at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$addDataPlaneProcessors$1(SocketServer.scala:281)

at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:158)

at kafka.network.SocketServer.addDataPlaneProcessors(SocketServer.scala:280)

at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors$1(SocketServer.scala:243)

at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors$1$adapted(SocketServer.scala:240)

at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)

at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)

at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)

at kafka.network.SocketServer.createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors(SocketServer.scala:240)

at kafka.network.SocketServer.startup(SocketServer.scala:123)

at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:406)

at io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable.startup(SupportedServerStartable.java:140)

at io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedKafka.main(SupportedKafka.java:66)

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem for configuration A client SSLEngine created with the provided settings can't connect to a server SSLEngine created with those settings.

at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.configure(SslFactory.java:111)

at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslChannelBuilder.configure(SslChannelBuilder.java:75)

... 17 more

[2021-03-10 07:45:21,051] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)

[2021-03-10 07:45:21,052] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Stopping socket server request processors (kafka.network.SocketServer)

[2021-03-10 07:45:21,053] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Stopped socket server request processors (kafka.network.SocketServer)

[2021-03-10 07:45:21,059] INFO Shutting down. (kafka.log.LogManager)

[2021-03-10 07:45:21,060] INFO Shutting down the log cleaner. (kafka.log.LogCleaner)

[2021-03-10 07:45:21,061] INFO [kafka-log-cleaner-thread-0]: Shutting down (kafka.log.LogCleaner)

[2021-03-10 07:45:21,061] INFO [kafka-log-cleaner-thread-0]: Stopped (kafka.log.LogCleaner)

[2021-03-10 07:45:21,061] INFO [kafka-log-cleaner-thread-0]: Shutdown completed (kafka.log.LogCleaner)

[2021-03-10 07:45:21,066] INFO Shutdown complete. (kafka.log.LogManager)

[2021-03-10 07:45:21,067] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)

[2021-03-10 07:45:21,177] INFO Session: 0x10004be2a200006 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)

[2021-03-10 07:45:21,177] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x10004be2a200006 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)

[2021-03-10 07:45:21,180] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)

[2021-03-10 07:45:21,181] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Shutting down (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)

[2021-03-10 07:45:21,383] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Stopped (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)

[2021-03-10 07:45:21,383] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Shutdown completed (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)

[2021-03-10 07:45:21,383] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Shutting down (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)

[2021-03-10 07:45:22,383] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Stopped (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)

[2021-03-10 07:45:22,383] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Shutdown completed (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)

[2021-03-10 07:45:22,384] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Shutting down (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)

[2021-03-10 07:45:22,385] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Stopped (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)

[2021-03-10 07:45:22,385] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Shutdown completed (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)

[2021-03-10 07:45:22,389] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Shutting down socket server (kafka.network.SocketServer)

[2021-03-10 07:45:22,478] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Shutdown completed (kafka.network.SocketServer)

[2021-03-10 07:45:22,485] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)

[2021-03-10 07:45:22,487] INFO Shutting down SupportedServerStartable (io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable)

[2021-03-10 07:45:22,487] INFO Closing BaseMetricsReporter (io.confluent.support.metrics.BaseMetricsReporter)

[2021-03-10 07:45:22,487] INFO Waiting for metrics thread to exit (io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable)

[2021-03-10 07:45:22,487] INFO Shutting down KafkaServer (io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable)

[2021-03-10 07:45:22,487] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Can anyone aware why this exception is coming and how to overcome this?

Comment: Typo? KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME should be KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION with a full absolute path

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer this will helps and i modified my environment in docker as follows                                                 
 KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION: /etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.broker.truststore.jks
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: "password"     and it is worked